# Minimize code as single instead of separate functions

Tags: jquery, html, css

in my code three input type=file elements for those 
css style is bind with button id of input tag. its working fine

```
//&lt;![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.new_Btn1').bind("click", function() {
        $('#html_btn1').click();

    });
    $('.new_Btn2').bind("click", function() {

        $('#html_btn2').click();
    });
    $('.new_Btn3').bind("click", function() {

        $('#html_btn3').click();
    });
});//]]&gt;
```

i want to minimize my code as single one instead of three, how i can achieve ?

Answer (score 4):

Give all your buttons the same class, e.g. `class="new_Btn"`, and a data attribute linking them to their `html_btn`, e.g.

```
<button class="new_Btn" data-file="html_btn1">...</button>
<button class="new_Btn" data-file="html_btn2">...</button>
...
```

Then use the JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".new_Btn").click(function() {
        $("#" + $(this).data('file')).click();
    });
});
```